# Call function in Controller using URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im comming from CodeIgniter.

There if you had a controller like this:

```
class Article extends CI_Controller{

    public function comments()
    {
        echo 'Look at this!';
    }
}
```

You could access the `comments()` function using the URL like this: `example.com/Article/comments`

---

**How could I do something similar in Laravel?**
The way I do it right now is specifiying a route like this:

```
Route::get('/Article/comments}', 'ArticleController@comments');
```

But I was hoping for a more dynamic way to do it as I don't want to keep on creating new routes for every function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way of dynamically calling controllers methods via URL, for Laravel users, is via RESTful Controllers:

```
<?php 

class ArticleController extends controller {

    public function getComment()
    {
        return 'This is only accesible via GET method';
    }

    public function postComment()
    {
        return 'This is only accesible via POST method';
    }

}
```

And create your route using telling Laravel this is a RESTful Controller:

```
Route::controller('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

Then if you follow

```
http://laravel.dev/articles/comments
```

Using your browser, you should receive:

```
This is only accesible via GET method
```

The way you name your controllers methods (getComment, postComment, deleteComment...) tells Laravel wich HTTP method should be used to call those methods.

Check the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

But you can also make it dynamic using PHP:

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    public function comments()
    {
        return 'Look at this!';
    }

    public function execute($method)
    {
        return $this->{$method}();
    }

}
```

Use a controller like this one:

```
Route::get('Article/{method}', 'ArticleController@execute');
```

Then you just have to

```
http://laravel.dev/Article/comments
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know you could do that in php!

Comment: Also wouldn't you add `return` before `$this->{$method}(); to return the view?

Comment: Yeah, of course, I just forgot to add it. :) Edited.

Comment: Mr. Ribeiro, won't `Route::controller('article', 'ArticleController')` achieve what he wants?

Comment: Yes, it would. Just edited to support a pure Laravel way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend that you stick with the laravel's way to create `REST controllers`, because that way you can have control over what `HTTP Verb` is being called with the controller method. The laravel way of doing this is just to add the `HTTP Verb` in front of the controller method, for your method `comments` if you want to specify a `GET` request in Laravel the name of the method would look like `getComments`.

For example, if you need to do a `GET` request for the `article/comments` URI, and then to create a new comment you want to use the same URI with another `HTTP` verb, lets say `POST`, you just need to do something like this:

```
class ArticleController extends BaseController{

    // GET: article/comments
    public function getComments()
    {
        echo 'Look at this!';
    }

    // POST: article/comments
    public function postComments()
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Further reading: 
http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Now for your specific answer, this is the Laravel way of doing what you requested:

```
class ArticleController extends BaseController{

    public function getComments()
    {
        echo 'Look at this!';
    }
}
```

and in the `routes.php` file you'll need to add the controller as follows:

```
Route::controller('articles', 'ArticleController');
```

Comment: You are right. I just inverted the order of my answers (it was still there) to set RESTful Controller as the recommended way.

Comment: thanks for the insight! Im going to stick to this method